# Is a windmill battleship in a medieval setting viable?

Tags: internal-consistency, ships, shipbuilding

Imagine a giant Chinese Treasure Ship-class. Could it ever be possible that a warship like that could be propelled by windmills and a water turbine/wheel  instead of sails?

Comment: Efficiency (and reliability) of this mechanism would be greatly inferior to propelling by sail.

Comment: A [battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship) is a *specific* kind of ship. "Battleship" is not a fancy way of saying "warship". Those 150 to 200 meters long wooden [Chinese treasure ships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_treasure_ship), if they existed at all, were cargo ships, not warships. The Chinese never had any battleships; when battleships were a thing China was not in a position to build or buy one, and when China became a great power again battleships were already museum pieces. And you are *vastly* overestimating Chinese medieval engineering.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting information. I edited the battleship into warship.
  When I mentioned the treasure ship, I only wished to use it as a size comparison. Because I was thinking of similarly  sized huge ass ship used for military purposes.

Comment: This exisited (the paddle wheel version, at least on paper): http://www.notechmagazine.com/2009/06/horse-powered-ferry-boat.html.  But note the last sentence in this article: " generally utilized for journeys of only a few miles."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In answer to your specific question (emphasis mine):

> Could it ever be **possible** that a battleship like that could be propelled by windmills and a water turbine/wheel instead of sails?

[Yes](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/1507825.stm).  With the right combination of technological advances and materials, it could probably be done.  The ship wouldn't move very quickly, though.

Which leads us to the problems:

1. Old wooden sailing ships, particularly warships, showed a fair amount of hull above the waterline, both to keep the water off the deck and to clear space for weapons.  This hull would work as a sail that could potentially counteract any propulsion generated by early propellers or water wheels.
2. Lacking efficient hydraulics or electrical systems, the energy loss from windmill to waterwheel would probably be substantial.
3. Materials science means that the *Revelation 2* can use carbon fibre blades to keep the weight down, and materials that won't tear apart in a high wind, and control surfaces that can readily reconfigure to prevent high winds from blowing the ship over.  The Chinese ships would lack all of these things.
4. Even given modern tech, a conventional sailing craft would outdo the ship in anything other than sailing directly into a headwind.  Given that the blades would have to be reefed in any sort of major winds, even that advantage wouldn't be much.

So is it *possible*?  Possibly, even probably, if someone were determined enough.  But it would be so wildly outperformed by a conventional sailplan, it wouldn't ever be worth it.  In answer to the *title* of your question, it definitely would not be *viable*.

Comment: Oh, that's sad... (:D) but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Keep sails for propulsion.  
Use windmills to power the war machines, e.g. winding up catapults and ballistas, or creating pressure for flamethrowers (look up "greek fire")